# analogue for ActiveRecords' "where" for plain Ruby's arrays

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Let's say i have an array of hashes with identical set of keys like:

```
array = [ 
  {attr1: val1, attr2: val2},
  {attr1: val3, attr2: val4} 
]
```

Thing is, i'd like to have some cool call like ActiveRecords' "where" to searh array above for specific elements. Something like

```
array.where(attr1: val1)
```

that will return all elements fitting the criteria. Using just plain Ruby.

Yes, there always is a good old `.each` but let's go full on pedal to the metal ruby-way here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `find`and `select`in ruby (for one or multiple results, respectively).

```
selected = array.select do |item|
  item[:attr1] == 'something'
end
```

`select` will pass each element of `array` to the block and pick those where the block returns a truthy value. 
`find` is similar but it will return the first element where the block returns a truthy value.

Comment: The term is "truthy" :)

Comment: Indeed, the same operation is called different names in different communities. In Relational Algebra, it's called a *Selection* or *Restriction*, in SQL, XQuery, and LINQ, it is called `Where`, the "standard", most widely-used name is `filter`, in Smalltalk, it is called `select`, Ruby calls it the same and also aliases it to `find_all`. It helps to be familiar with those different names, e.g. *Projection* (Relational Algebra), `Select` (SQL, XQuery, LINQ – note: this is *not* the same thing as `select` in Smalltalk and Ruby!), `transform` (C++), `collect` (Smalltalk, Ruby), `map` ("standard")

Comment: @JörgWMittag i don't think that `map`and `select`are the same

Comment: @pascalbetz: Which `select` are you talking about? The operation that is called `Select` in SQL, XQuery, LINQ, and the .NET collections framework transforms each element of the collection into a different element but keeps the structure of the collection. That's the same operation that is called `collect` in Smalltalk and Ruby, `transform` in C++, *Projection* in Relational Algebra (usually denoted `σ`), and `map` almost everywhere. It is *not* the same operation that is called `select` in Smalltalk and Ruby. *That* operation is called `Where` in SQL, XQuery, LINQ, and the .NET collections …

Comment: … framework, aliased to `find_all` in Ruby, called `filter` almost everywhere else and a *Selection* or *Restriction* in Relational Algebra. It is unfortunately confusing that SQL, the most common implementation of Relational Algebra uses `SELECT` to refer to a *Projection* and not a *Selection* and uses something else (`WHERE`) for a *Selection*, and that other communities use the term `select` for a selection, especially since you'll often mix SQL code with other code, where the term `select` now has two different meanings.

Comment: @JörgWMittag i was referring to `select` (or 'find_all') and 'map' (or 'collect') in ruby.

Comment: @pascalbetz: Okay, that's exactly the kind of confusion I alluded to :-D Ruby `map` == SQL `SELECT`. Ruby `select` == SQL `WHERE`. Ruby `select` != SQL `SELECT`. There is generally no problem with this, as long as we don't mix and match different domains. Unfortunately, especially in web programming, that is precisely what we are doing, where we mix SQL, ECMAScript, maybe XQuery, and possibly at least one if not multiple other languages. The  Ruby names are inherited from Smalltalk, where they are part of a small rhyming joke, with the most important collection methods being …

Comment: `collect:`, `select:`, `reject:`, `detect:`, and `inject:into:`.